# Alinha na mesma linha rowEdit e demais botões no PrimeFaces

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

Estou com problema onde a minha `dataTable` possui a propriedade `editable` setada para `true`. Permitindo a edição da linha que o usuário seleciona.

Pois bem, ao colocar um botão para excluir por exemplo estou com problema que o botão de editar não permanece na mesma linha, dando uma quebra de linha no mesmo e deixando os dois botões em níveis diferentes.

[image: Print do <code>datatable</code>]

E ai gostaria de saber o que fazer para poder alinhar, já tentei colocar dentro um `panelGrid` mas ai o `rowEditor` deixa de funcionar.

Código abaixo:

```
<p:dataTable id="vigenciaCorrente" editable="true"
    value="#{tabelaTaxaBean.pojo.vigenciaCorrente.faixas}"
    var="corrente" sortBy="prazoMinimo">

    <f:facet name="header">
        <div align="left">
            <p:outputLabel value="Vigência de " />
            <p:outputLabel
                value="#{tabelaTaxaBean.pojo.vigenciaCorrente.dataInicial}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </p:outputLabel>
            <p:outputLabel value=" a "></p:outputLabel>
            <p:outputLabel
                value="#{tabelaTaxaBean.pojo.vigenciaCorrente.dataFinal}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </p:outputLabel>
            <p:outputLabel value=" (vigência corrente)"></p:outputLabel>
        </div>
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Prazo (em meses)">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel
                    value="#{corrente.prazoMinimo} a #{corrente.prazoMaximo}" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText label="Prazo inicial"
                    value="#{corrente.prazoMinimo}" size="8" maxlength="3"
                    onkeypress="mascara(this, soNumeros)" required="true" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <p:inputText label="Prazo final"
                    value="#{corrente.prazoMaximo}" size="8" maxlength="3"
                    onkeypress="mascara(this, soNumeros)" required="true" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Taxa de juros">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{corrente.taxaJuros}">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:outputLabel>
                <p:outputLabel value="%" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText label="Taxa de juros"
                    value="#{corrente.taxaJuros}"
                    onkeypress="mascara(this,valorMonetario)" size="11"
                    maxlength="6" required="true">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Taxa diferenciada para o banco/empresa">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{corrente.taxaDiferenciadaParaBanco}">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:outputLabel>
                <p:outputLabel value="%" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText label="Taxa diferenciada para o banco/empresa"
                    value="#{corrente.taxaDiferenciadaParaBanco}"
                    onkeypress="mascara(this,valorMonetario)" size="11"
                    maxlength="6">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Comissão">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{corrente.comissao}">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:outputLabel>
                <p:outputLabel value="%" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText label="Comissão" value="#{corrente.comissao}"
                    onkeypress="mascara(this,valorMonetario)" size="11"
                    maxlength="6" required="true">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Complemento">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{corrente.complementoComissao}">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:outputLabel>
                <p:outputLabel value="%" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText label="Complemento"
                    value="#{corrente.complementoComissao}"
                    onkeypress="mascara(this,valorMonetario)" size="11"
                    maxlength="6">
                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" minFractionDigits="2"
                        maxFractionDigits="2" />
                </p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Ação" style="width: 5%">
        <p:rowEditor />
        <p:commandButton update=":form:vigenciaCorrentePanel"
            process=":form:vigenciaCorrentePanel" title="Excluir"
            value="Excluir">
            <p:collector
                removeFrom="#{tabelaTaxaBean.pojo.vigenciaCorrente.faixas}"
                value="#{corrente}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <div align="right">
            <p:commandButton id="btnFaixaCorrente"
                process="btnFaixaCorrente" value="Adicionar faixa"
                update=":dialogAdicionarFaixa" oncomplete="dlgFaixa.show();">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                    target="#{tabelaTaxaBean.vigenciaTipo}" value="corrente" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </div>
    </f:facet>

</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, force para que não haja quebra de linha na célula em questão e defina uma largura fixa. Exemplo dos estilos *inline*:

```xml
<p:column headerText="Ação" 
    style="width: 200px; white-space: nowrap;">
```

O elemento `<p:rowEditor>` gera uma `div` no HTML final. Você deve aplicar nele os seguintes estilos, para evitar que o `div` ocuppe a linha toda e seu alinhamento seja no centro:

```css
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Para colocar tudo isso em CSS puroi, é possível definir uma classe para a coluna com o atributo `styleClass` e então aplicar os etilos com um seletor CSS.

O stributo `styleClass` abaixo define a classe CSS `coluna-acao` na coluna "Ação":

```xml
<p:column headerText="Ação" styleClass="coluna-acao">
```

E os estilos abaixo numa tag ou arquivo de estilos vai fazer a "mágica", não necessitando colocar estilos inline:

```css
.coluna-acao {
    width: 200px; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
.coluna-acao div.ui-row-editor {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Vamos analisar o que faz cada linha. Primeiro há o estilo a ser aplicado nas células:

- `width: 200px`: define uma largura fixa para as células
- `white-space: nowrap`: evita que o espaço entre os elementos da célula (botões) cause uma quebra de linha. Isso também é necessário porque há um CSS para o `div` com o botão editar com um atributo `after` que adiciona um caracter após a `div`.

Depois o estilo aplicado ao botão editar da célula, que na verdade fica dentro de uma tag `div`:

- `display: inline-block`: o component `div` por padrão tem seu atributo `display` com o valor `block`, o que significa que ele sempre quebra a linha depois. Mudamos o valor para que o outro botão possa continuar na mesma linha.
- `vertical-align: middle`: faz com que os componentes sejam alinhados horizontalmente ao centro um do outro.

É claro que não tive como testar com a sua tela, então provavelmente será necessário ajustar alguns valores ou estilos de acordo com seu sistema.

Comment: Cara, vou te falar que acho que ninguém tem essa solução que você postou, porque ontem rodei o google e não achei, poderia por favor explicar quais suas intenções com estes css. Obrigado!

Comment: @Macario1983 Adicionei explicações na resposta. Também removi um atributo que havia colocado por engano (sujeira de testes). Espero que tenha ficado claro agora. Eu não cheguei a pesquisar por uma solução na internet, fiz usando o editor do Chrome no *showcase* do PrimeFaces. Já estou acostumado, pois embora o PF seja bastante utilizado, não existem soluções para muitos ajustes finos.

Comment: A única coisa que observei que após trocar o botão excluir por uma figura, eles não ficam no mesmo nível em altura, alterei o vertical align para top e deu certo...Mas já ta valendo! Obrigado